# Stop app termination after each test case in XCTest

Tags: xctest, termination

I am new to XCTest, I have a small sample project for my app where I have 10 test cases and each test case is interdependent the problem I am facing here is if I run my test suit after each test case my app is terminating and calling next method,I don't want it to close the app but it has to continue from the same place where test case one had finished

Thanks in advance

Comment: My problem is different actually, I have a app in android and a app in iPhone, for example from android device i will send "HI" message,I want to check is it received in iPhone and vise versa, so as the example states i have to toggle between 2 devices so i need the app in its initial state and function to be divided in different methods

Comment: I do not understand what your comment has to do with your question. I suggest that you edit your question and try to formulate it as precise as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Tests should be independent from each other. Remember that the algorithm for the running order of Xcode tests could change at any time. Having tests that depend on each other is a fragile system, since if one test fails, it's likely that the state for the next test will be wrong, and all subsequent tests will fail, providing falsely negative feedback.

If you must have tests dependent on each other, just put all your code into a single test with multiple assertions. You probably want to set `continueAfterFailure` to true.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad idea to launch app only once to execute test cases as the sequence of test cases is not known in xcode ui test.

But if you want it badly, here's the solution. In swift 2.2 and 2.3, I use

```
dispatch_once
```

for this kind of requirements.

In your test case class, i think you use

```
XCUIApplication.launch() method in  setUp() method.
```

you have to use dispatch_once() here. if you use this dispatch_once for XCUIApplication.launch(), this will only launch the application once.

here is the solution for swift 2.2 and 2.3:

```
 private static var launchAppOnce: () = {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    //do some code if you needed after launch app before run test cases.
}()

struct Static {
    static var dispatchOnceToken: Int = 0
}

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false
      _ = urclassname.launchAppOnce
}

override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}
```

use the above code in your test case classes.
This will launch app only once and start the next test case from where it finish the previous test cases.

Comment: have you got any solution, if not please check the updated answer. if yes please post your answer.